# Do I have the right for remote identity verification?

Tags: banking, italy

Bit of a weird sitaution here: I did my PhD in Italy some years ago and have a bank account there. I thought I had emptied it so didn't think about that account for quite some time.

I was recently contacted by the bank that I still have some money there. Problem is that my online banking account is blocked (due to being inactive for too long). To reactivate it, they require me to phyiscally come to their bank. This is not really an option for me, since I live too far away now.

There are online/virtual options to confirm someone's identity. My bank is adamant that I have to physically come to them to confirm my identity, I feel likey they are effectively denying me access to my money? Do I have the 'right' to have my identity confirmed remotely?